# TFS area path and charts

Tags: charts, tfs

in my project we have an area path structure like this:

```
    |
    + feature a
    |  |- area X
    |  |- area Y   
    + feature b
    |  |- area X
    |  |- area Y
```

I like the simple charting available for queries in TFS's web view. So I created a query plus a diagram.

### Issue:

TFS takes only the last id of the area path to group elements.
In other words - result looks like

```
    |
    |  x
    |  x    x
    +---------
       |    |
area X /    \ area Y
```

but i actually want

```
    |           x
    |  x        x
    |  x    x   x    x
    +-------------------
       |    |   |    |
       |    |   |    \ feat b, area Y
       |    |   \ feat b, area X
       |    \ feat a, area Y
       \ feat a, area Y
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your query?

Comment: Which information is missing? Project state is confidential ;)

Comment: the query looks like:

    work item type == Bug
    and assigend to == @me

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is expected. When you select **Area Path** or **Iteration Path**, only the leaf node appears in the chart. The leaf node is the last node of the full path. If your query contains a mixed level of leaf nodes, your chart might not reflect expected results.
Use **Node Name**, the area path leaf node, to see if that improves your results. More information, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/report/charts

You can consider submitting a UserVoice at website: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

[image]

[image]

Comment: Node Name gives the same result. I can use Area ID which is not human readable.
I consider submitting a UserVoice. From my POV Node Name is the better wording to describe leaf node while something called "path" should be a path

Comment: Currently, it's not able to have the full path in the chart. You can consider submitting a UserVoice at website: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015, product team will evaluate it seriously.

Comment: can I use your screenshots?

Comment: everyone my upvote here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13580652-evaluate-the-area-path-as-full-path-in-tfs-for-c